# Microphone getting feedback random levels from my amp

Tags: guitar, amplifiers, effects-pedal, microphones

I bought [this microphone](https://a.co/d/galtRF2) so to eliminate wind sounds for singing, where I play acoustic guitar live in a restaurant, and with my electroacoustic guitar Ibañez model GA5TCE. I am able to play, sing, but it feeds from my amp doing a buzz sound, so I have to lower the volume from my mixer software (VOICEMEETER in my PC) and the amount I lower changes day by day, in the same place (weird?). Am I doing this right? Or how can I sing using that microphone at the same time of connecting my Ibañez to my Line 6 PODxt Live giving extraordinary guitar set to my 65W amp?

I am connecting the microphone to an adapter that I found in my gaming earphones (pasting picture below). That's the only way I found to make that microphone sound with my PC. If I connect it directly, my voice doesn't sound.

So, then I connect USB cable to the Line 6 pedal and the pedal sends everything to the amp.

[image: adapter I mention, right side has Aux 3.5mm input]

Comment: That's quite a setup! It's interesting that the microphone's connector shows three stripes; most PC mic inputs are mono and would use a mic that only has one. Note, in the Amazon reviews one user says "No funciona en mi PC," with a picture (or was that you?)! It doesn't solve your immediate problem, but I bet a better mic, with XLR output, might sound better as well as be easier to work with.

Comment: The buzz sound is a ground loop

Comment: Yes @AndyBonner thanks! Anytime I can tell you how I did it. It works in my PC using that converter I mention. It looks like anytime a "K-Song Live  Sound Card" is necessary for that microphone. Anyway, to find this setup solution costed me several combination tries and iterations of changing cables positions also with my Line 6 until I found this works. It works actually and I plan to keep using it, but the main reason I report here my question is to know what you all think about the random levels of buzz feedback each day. I saw that one day it's needed to lower -16db, and other day -25db!!

Comment: @Yorik by ground loop you mean that the ground influences in the feedback buzz? Or it's about the electronic ground of the microphone plug to the PC?

Comment: you have an amp plugged in and a PC plugged in so you have "multiple paths to ground" or "multiple routes for current flow between two nodes". ( https://music.stackexchange.com/search?q=ground+loop ) If your PC is a laptop, try unplugging and running on battery and see if this resolves the noise.